# how can I set a %define in a spec file based on the version of another RPM?

Tags: rpm, specifications

I need to set the value of a %define declaration in a spec file based on the version of another RPM that is supposed to be installed already in the system.

I already tried this and I'm having errors:

```
if [ -n "$(rpm -qa otherrpm)" ]; then
  %define THIS_VALUE value
else
  %define THIS_VALUE anothervalue
endif
```

Comment: Can you post the errors ? It isn't a good idea to depend on another package this way.

Answer (score 1):

If your package depends on package `foo`, then you need to prepare the spec file appropriately, e.g.,

A build time requirement of package `foo` ( if a certain version, then make it explicit ), should have

```
BuildRequires: foo >= x.y.z-r
```

A run time requirement of package `foo` ( if a certain version, then make it explicit), should have

```
Requires: foo >= x.y.z-r
```

You can then use define for other conditions, e.g.,

```
%global with_foo  1  # 1 means you need foo for build and install

%if %{with_foo}
%define THIS_VALUE value
BuildRequires: foo
Requires: foo
%else
%define THIS_VALUE anothervalue
%endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing shell execution with RPM macro evaluation. You need to run the shell code at macro evaluation time, using the `%()` syntax. For instance, like this:

```
%define other_rpm_version %(rpm -q otherrpm | cut -d - -f 2)

%if "%other_rpm_version" == "1.0.0"
%define THIS_VALUE value
%else
%define THIS_VALUE othervalue
%endif
```